# Dynamic text fields buggy? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a function which updates my dynamic fields, but nothing happens...any ideas on what could be wrong?

```
function updateBar(){
    progressBar.scaleX = percentToLevel;
    levelText.text = level.toString();
    expText.text = String(currentExp);
    nextLvlText.text = String(baseLevelExp);
}
```

The progressBar line works. The rest don't. No errors. I checked the instance names of the text fields and they are all correct....what could it be?

Comment: Are you 100% sure level is not null when you calculate `level.toStirng()`? Can you add `trace(level)` above that line to check?

Comment: The lvl appears in the trace.

Comment: I just added a static value...it doesn't appear as well, so I tried adding new dynamic text fields, and they dont work as well.....any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I did not embed the font. When I did all was well.